What is the purpose of Redis queues in Conductor OSS?
I am studying Conductor OSS. I have deployed it with the following configuration:
conductor.queue.type=redis_standalone
conductor.db.type=postgres
conductor.indexing.enabled=true
conductor.elasticsearch.url=http://es:9200

After starting, I see that a task is created for the workers in Redis. I thought the entire payload would be passed there, but only the task ID is transmitted. What is the purpose of these queues in Redis? I understand that the workers find their tasks in the Redis queue and then retrieve their payload from Elasticsearch or PostgreSQL. What is the point of having queues in Redis? How does this affect performance?
